# Python crawl web HttpEror 500 using urlib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I use `url lib`, `urllib2`, `cookie lib` to scrape a `web:get` the login page and post the data.

```
def getpage():

codeurl=r"http://www.xxx/sign_in"

request=urllib2.Request(codeurl)

response=urllib2.urlopen(request)

return response

def parsecode(response):

"""
parse the login page to get the changed code
 """

pattern=re.compile(r"""<meta.*?csrf-token.*?content=(.*?)\s/>""")
code=re.findall(pattern,response.read())[0]

return code


def Hand():

"""
deal with cookie and header
"""
headers={
        "Referer":"xxx",
        "User-Agent":"xxx"
        }
ck=cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
handle=urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(ck)
openner=urllib2.build_opener(handle)
head=[]
for key,value in headers.items():
    tup=(key,value)
    head.append(tup)
openner.addheaders = head
return openner


def postdata(code,openner):

"""
post the data xxx.com needed
"""
logurl=r"http://www.jianshu.com/sessions"
sign_in={"name":"xxx","password":"xxx","authenticity_token":code}
data=urllib.urlencode(sign_in).encode("utf-8")
x=openner.open(logurl,data)
for item in ck:
    print item
```

**However,I met this bug:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "jianshu.py", line 80, in 
>       postdata(code,op)
>
> File "jianshu.py", line 43, in postdata
>       x=openner.open(logurl,data)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly missing a ' in between the 'r' and 'http://...' this line:

codeurl=r"http://www.xxx/sign_in"